# addProximityAlert and KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING

Tags: java, android

In the documentation, when discussing `addProximityAlert` , the description about Intent confuses me a bit. Specifically this part..

> The fired Intent will have a boolean extra added with key
>   KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING. If the value is true, the device is entering
>   the proximity region; if false, it is exiting.

This may sound like a dumb question but.. how do I get true or false when I'm entering/ or in  a certain radius of a location.

I'm not sure how this would work exactly.

Do I have to write my own code and check when I'm in the proximity of my location and then have it return true and false as I'm exiting?

I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this works in conjunction with a `BroadcastReceiver`. You might set the `addProximityAlert()` method to fire the `onReceive()` method on this receiver, which will provide you an `Intent` as a parameter and then get that extra `Boolean` called `KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING`. So, step by step:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

// You need to declare an Intent for your class and declare a PendingIntent on it,
// so it might be passed to the addProximityAlert method as the fifth parameter.
Intent intent = new Intent("com.yourdomain.yourproject.MyAlert");
PendingIntent proxIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

lm.addProximityAlert(your_latitude, your_longitude, RADIUS_IN_METERS, -1, proxIntent);
```

Explaination of the parameters set here:

- **your_longitude**: The longitude you want to calculate the Radius on
- **your_latitude**: The latitude you want to calculate the Radius on
- **RADIUS_IN_METERS**: This is a constant defined by yourself where you specify the length of the radius you want to trace from the coordinate defined by the above parameters. If you set it to be, for example, `1000`, you're saying that if someone gets closer than 1 km to your coordinate, the `KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING` will be `true` if the previous execution of `onReceive()` was more distant than 1 km, and analogously otherwise.
- **-1**: This is the time in milliseconds after which the proximity alert will stop. If set to `-1`, it will never expire.
- **proxIntent**: The proximity `Intent` that will fire your `BroadcastReceiver`.

Further, you'll also need this:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.yourdomain.yourproject.MyAlert"); 
registerReceiver(new AlertOnProximityReceiver(), filter);
```

This way you're activating the Receiver for the filter you just set. This will fire the `onReceive()` event on it. So now, there's just one thing left, declare the `BroadcastReceiver`.

```
public class AlertOnProximityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    Boolean getting_closer = intent.getBooleanExtra(LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING, false);
    if (getting_closer)
      Log.d("Radius", "Hey, I just entered your radius!");
    else
      Log.d("Radius", "I just exited your radius!");
  }          
}
```

**---- UPDATE ----**

I'm now seeing this in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addProximityAlert%28double,%20double,%20float,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29):

> Throws
>
> SecurityException     if ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission is not present

So make sure you include this permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`addProximityAlert`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addProximityAlert%28double,%20double,%20float,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) you specify the "special area" which should fire the proximity alert using the arguments it have (**bold**)

> Parameters
>
> **latitude**  the latitude of the central point of the alert
>   region
>
> **longitude** the longitude of the central point of the alert
>   region
>
> **radius**    the radius of the central point of the alert region, in
>   meters expiration
>
> time for this proximity alert, in milliseconds, or
>   -1 to indicate no expiration
>
> intent    a PendingIntent that will be used to generate an Intent to fire when entry to or exit from the alert
>   region is detected

When the user enters the area declared when you called the method the `intent` is called and inside this you found this extra `KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING` which alerts you if you enter or leave this area.

I don't know really how it works, but it could be something like:

> To know it will check if he is in the radius latitude and longitudine, if yes send the intent when he leaves call the intent again passing "false".

The answer to your question is anyway you shouldn't care about this fact, it's done by the System and you don't need to do anything.

The only thing you need to do is to read this extra and use it if you need.

From documentation:

> Due to the approximate nature of position estimation, if the device passes through the given area briefly, it is possible that no Intent will be fired. Similarly, an Intent could be fired if the device passes very close to the given area but does not actually enter it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code it will help you a lot.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
    PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
    locationManager.addProximityAlert(
            lat, // the latitude of the central point of the alert region
            lon, // the longitude of the central point of the alert region
            POINT_RADIUS, // the radius of the central point of the alert region, in meters
            PROX_ALERT_EXPIRATION, // time for this proximity alert, in milliseconds, or -1 to indicate no expiration
            proximityIntent // will be used to generate an Intent to fire when entry to or exit from the alert region is detected
            );
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROX_ALERT_INTENT); 
    registerReceiver(new ProximityIntentReceiver(orderStatusObject.getBidId()), filter);
```

Class - for Approximate Alert broadcast

```
public class ProximityIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1000;
public Context mcontext;//Context of calling BroadCast Receiver
private String bidId;   //Hold the value of bid Id

public ProximityIntentReceiver() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public ProximityIntentReceiver(String bidId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.bidId = bidId;
}
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;


    Boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);
    if (entering) {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "entering");
    }
    else {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "exiting");
    }

    sendNotification(context);

}
public void sendNotification(Context mcontext){
    // String extra=arg1.getExtras().getString("alert").toString();
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String message = "You are near of driver pickup area.";
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mcontext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,message, when);
    String title = "Proximity Alert!"; 
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mcontext, 0,notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(mcontext, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```